# How to display today's operating hours

Tags: javascript

I'd like to have a box on our new library website that states what the hours the library is open for that particular day. That way any time they go to the site they will know just when the library is open that day. I will also have a link to go to a page with broader details about the hours etc.

I'm pretty new to javascript but I'm assuming that that's how this would be handled. Even if I could be pointed in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If the content is static, you wouldn't need javascript for this. you'd just create a HTML element with the list of the opening time and then style it with CSS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Date.getDay()`<sup>[MDN docs]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function will return an integer from 0-6 specifying the day of the week (where 0 is Sunday). Then you can just create an array with the hours and get the element that corresponds to the current day.

```
var dayOfWeek = (new Date).getDay();
var hours = ["Closed",          // Sunday
             "7 AM to 5 PM",    // Monday
             "8 AM to 5 PM",    // Tuesday
             "9 AM to 3 PM",    // Wednesday
             "8 AM to 5 PM",    // Thursday
             "9 AM to 2 PM",    // Friday
             "10 AM to 2 PM"];  // Saturday
var todaysHours = hours[dayOfWeek];
```

You can see a demo of this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZQTH/).

Comment: That is spectacular! And perfectly answers my question. One wrinkle that I didn't ask about: is there a way to account for variant days, like how our hours change during the week of spring break?

Comment: @Brad Yes, you would have to create some sort of `isSpringBreakWeek` function so that it could change based on whether or not it is spring break. That said, Spring break isn't necessarily the same time each year and you might have to change the page manually.